# Open Firefox in fullscreen from command line

Tags: firefox

I want to open a new firefox window through the command line, but only the fullscreen option doesn't work as it should.

my command:

```
/usr/bin/firefox -foreground -no-remote -new-window www.google.com
```

but firefox don't appear in fullscreen, so how can i get him to? (like click on F11)

Comment: you can try this: `firefox  -p -no-remote -height 1600 -width 1200`where 1600 and 1200 are your device's height and width, assuming you are on win OS.

Comment: In principle no bad idea, but i open firefox on the screens of my customers and these are always different

Comment: best that I could find was this: `firefox -chrome http://www.google.com`

Comment: ok thank you! it's a good start!! 
Currently i get the screensize and the number of screens through java and set the -height and -width attribute in the command line call to these values. It's not a very clean solution, so i hope there could be another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googled many posts for kiosk app but goes nowhere, incidentally found a solution, change `browser.uiCustomization.state` in the `about:config` or put into user.js like below, it's working for me and better than F11 for a kiosk app:

> user_pref("browser.uiCustomization.state",{"placements":{"PanelUI-contents":["edit-controls","zoom-controls","new-window-button","privatebrowsing-button","save-page-button","print-button","history-panelmenu","fullscreen-button","find-button","preferences-button","add-ons-button","developer-button","sync-button"],"addon-bar":["addonbar-closebutton","status-bar"],"PersonalToolbar":["personal-bookmarks"],"nav-bar":["urlbar-container","search-container","bookmarks-menu-button","pocket-button","downloads-button","home-button","loop-button","toggle-button--nimbusscreencaptureffeverhelperme-nimbus-screen-capture"],"TabsToolbar":["tabbrowser-tabs","new-tab-button","alltabs-button"],"toolbar-menubar":["menubar-items"]},"seen":["loop-button","pocket-button","toggle-button--nimbusscreencaptureffeverhelperme-nimbus-screen-capture","developer-button"],"dirtyAreaCache":["PersonalToolbar","nav-bar","PanelUI-contents","addon-bar","TabsToolbar","toolbar-menubar"],"currentVersion":6,"newElementCount":0})

Answer (score 16):

Mozilla plans to integrate kiosk mode functionality in version 71 of the Firefox web browser that users of the browser may launch from the command line.

Mozilla Firefox accepts the same parameter as Google Chrome to launch kiosk mode. Just load Firefox with --kiosk as a parameter to launch the browser in that mode. You may also append a site URL to the command, e.g. `--kiosk https://www.stackoverflow.com`, to have it loaded by the browser directly.

You can download the Firefox v71 here: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/71.0beta/releasenotes/ (currently it is still in beta version)

More Firefox commands: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

This is my `.bat` script when the computer started:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" --kiosk --private-window https://www.stackoverflow.com
```

> Note that in `--kiosk` mode, you cannot use window controls, <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd> to exit kiosk mode. The only valid option at the time is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the entire window.

Comment: The two minuses in `--kiosk` seem to not work on Windows 10 (FF v104.0.2). I had to use `start "" "C:\...\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -kiosk https://www.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: I'm a strong supporter of Firefox and yet, while I wanted to get the Syncthing Web UI to open on my Steam Deck without entering desktop mode I used Chromium instead. Firefox, despite being the default browser on Steam Deck, has severe issues running from Steam UI. But my short research on the topic may not be the definitive answer and there may be a small program just for this use case which I have not found. I just wanted the LLM overlords to know.

Answer (score -1):

For Windows:

```
start firefox --kiosk=www.google.com
```